# How to unscrew screws that are barely accessible?

Tags: screws

I need to remove the face of a fake drawer that is screwed from behind. Unfortunately, a kitchen sink is preventing me from using a screwdriver. There is approximatively 4cm of space. The screw head is a PZ2. Is there a tool can could help me remove this screw ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For tight spots, they make Offset Screwdrivers.

[image][image]

They're manufactured by many different companies, with many different drive variations.

Comment: I still have not tested but I like it. That's the kind of tool I had in mind.

Answer (score 25):

You can use a ratchet handle with a screwdriver bit attachment, like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there any need for a special attachment to hold the bit? I've always just used a regular socket of the appropriate size.  If you're really cramped for space a ratchet handle with a build in screwdriver bit socket can be more compact than a standard ratchet + socket combination.  ex http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0400009762

Comment: @DanNeely that really depends on the ratchet handle.  Some fit the bits without connectors, some don't.

Answer (score 6):

If you have them a socket driver with the appropriate attachments is the best way, if not then you may have to improvise.

Using what you're likely to have in hand you can make a rig using a PZ2 bit and a locking pliers. You lock the pliers on the driver end of the bit, maneuver it into the gap, then use one hand to stabilize the bit and push it into the screw while you use the other to turn the bit using the pliers. Also, you can use a closed end of a combination wrench to turn the bit.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few solutions that are actually usable if you need to improvise. They are clearly not optimal, but it would certainly have helped me at the time I asked the question. I didn't own a multi tool back then. T
he four solutions are based on Leatherman multi-tools (Sidekick and Rebar) in this specific case.

Leatherman multitools are sometimes sold with a flat carabiner which can drive bits.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I keep a 1/4" combination spanner in a bit set for the times when even my ratchet handles are too bulky.  The ring end in particular is very useful for this task

Answer (score 2):

**Right Angle Driver**: (likely available at your local store from random manufacturers)

[image]

[irwin.com](http://www.irwin.com/tools/impact-accessories/impact-right-angle-drill-drive-tool)

Answer (score 2):

For tight places where there also isn't room to rotate a tool, a low-profile solution is a "squeeze wrench":

[image]

Different sockets or drivers, including special screwdriver bits, are held in a rotating collar.  Without moving the wrench, you loosen or tighten the fastener by squeezing the handle, which works a ratchet mechanism to turn the bit.  They are pretty widely available at places that sells tools.  They are very handy, but note that they won't give you heavy leverage if brute force is needed on a frozen fastener (well, unless you have the strength to crush walnuts in your bare hands).

Answer (score 0):

In a really, really tight space, reach in with a nail that has a head that will fit in the screw slot and use the head to twist the screw a bit at a time.