# How to unscrew a screw that I can't access frontally?

Tags: wood

I need to unscrew a screw that I can't access frontally.

How can I do it?

Googling a bit I was thinking of a Torque Wrench, do you think it's the right choice?

Comment: A picture would help. I remove screws on the back side of things all the time. I don’t see how a torque wrench would be any different than any other wrench.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean you can get to the front but don't have enough room for even a really short screwdriver? If so, what kind of screw head? If not, which part of the screw do you see? Pictures might help.

Comment: I found my answer..
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/21400/how-to-unscrew-screws-that-are-barely-accessible

Comment: Screwing/unscrewing from behind can be just as enjoyable.   Just make sure you are in the right slot.

Answer (score 4):

Use an angled (or offset<sup>*</sup>) screw driver:

[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of chelseaclockwallpaper.blogspot.com. First reasonably small image I found for what I was after</sup>

There are also ratcheting right-angle screwdrivers such as:

[image]
<sup>Image courtesy of harborfreight.com</sup>

If you don't have enough room for even that, use pliers to grip the head. You might use locking pliers (ViceGrip™ is one brand name) depending on how tight the screw is in.

<sup>*</sup>*As noted in a comment by Greg Hill. Thanks!*

Comment: Some call the Z-shape screwdriver an "offset screwdriver."

Comment: @GregHill, see edit. ;)